# CI/CD integration problem when using google-cloud-build with github push as trigger for Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline using one of my public GitHub repositories as the source for Cloud Run (fully-managed) service using Cloud Build. I am using a Dockerfile initialized in root folder of the repository with source configuration parameter initialized as `/Dockerfile` when setting up the cloud build trigger. (to continuously deploy new revisions from source repository)

When, I initialize the cloud run instance, I face the following error:

[image: Error after initializing the instance]

Moreover, when I try to run my cloud build trigger manually, it shows the following error:

[image: When using run option of cloud build trigger]

I also tried editing continuous deployment settings by setting it to **automatically detect Dockerfile/cloudbuild.yaml**. After that, build process becomes successful but the revision are not getting updated. I've also tried deploying a new revision and then triggering cloud build trigger but it isn't still able to pick the latest build from container registry.

I am positive that my Dockerfile and application code are working properly since I've previously submitted the build on Container registry using Google Cloud Shell and have tested it manually after deploying it to cloud run.

Need help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPPERCASE letters in the image path aren't allowed. Chnage `Toxicity-Detector` to `toxicity-detector`